# Laravel 4: Add username to every route url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

How do I add username to url?

Example: www.domain.com/feeds/username

I want to add username to every route url.

::Route::

```
Route::get('feeds', array('before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'feeds', 'uses' => 'FeedsController@getFeedsPage'));
```

::Controller::

```
class FeedsController extends BaseController {
    public function getFeedsPage() {
        return View::make('feeds.index');
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this, declare the route like this (Notice `{username}`):

```
Route::get('feeds/{username}', array('before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'feeds', 'uses' => 'FeedsController@getFeedsPage'));
```

Declare the `class`:

```
class FeedsController extends BaseController {

    // Use a parameter to receive the username
    public function getFeedsPage($username) {
        // You may access the username passed via route
        // inside this method using $username variable
        return View::make('feeds.index')->with('username', $username);
    }
}
```

Now you may use a `URI` like these:

```
www.domain.com/feeds/username1
www.domain.com/feeds/michaelsangma
```

Comment: **@WereWolf**

It worked! Thanks.

View loads perfectly, but, for some reason CSS was not working. I changed the CSS link URL one step up, and now it works fine.

Thanks again.